# How to retrieve the most recently created files in a directory

Tags: python, arrays, linux, file, directory

I'd like to retrieve an array of the lastest created files of a directory. Every set of files are created within the same period of time - with a margin of 1000 milliseconds.

The first 4 files in this list are created within the same 1000 millisec. and I'd like retrieve only those 4 files:

```
sceflh.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:46.100000000
rgxanx.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:45.900000000
byoiup.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:45.700000000
rrqgnh.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:45.500000000
sqthcv.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:40.320000000
ebrmvv.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:40.200000000
xzvsnt.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:40.110000000
ckiinz.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:40.100000000
```

How would I go around retrieving such list? This is what I've got, which just gives me all the files in the directory:

```
def get_files(directory):
    files = []
    for file in [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory,f))]:
        files.append( '{0}/{1}'.format(directory, file) )
    return files
```

**Edit: Here is my final code**

```
import os

def get_recent_files(directory, threshold=0.9):
    files = sorted(get_files(directory), key=os.path.getmtime,reverse=True)
    filtered = filter(lambda x: os.path.getmtime(files[0]) - os.path.getmtime(x) <= threshold, files)
    return filtered

def get_files(directory):
    files = []
    for file in [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f))]:
        files.append( '{0}/{1}'.format(directory, file) )
    return files

for file in get_recent_files("images", 0.900):
    print(file)
```

Comment: Which os are you on?

Comment: If you are referring to the last time the file was modified, you have a chance.  However, most file systems do not store the creation time of files and there is simply no way to do what you are asking.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ok, last modified it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your files by modification date on linux/creation date on windows using [os.path.getmtime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime)

```
sorted(get_files("."),key = os.path.getmtime,reverse = True)[:5]
```

To just get the name of the file:

```
[os.path.split(x)[1]  for x in  sorted(get_files("."),key = os.path.getmtime,reverse = True)[:5]]
```

Using your original function and a threshold:

```
files =  sorted(get_files("."), key=os.path.getmtime,reverse=True)
filtered =  filter(lambda x: os.path.getmtime(files[0]) - os.path.getmtime(x) <= .09,files)
```

To match something like your question:

import os
from datetime import datetime

```
def get_files(directory):
    files = []
    for file in [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory,f))]:
        da = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file))
        files.append( '{0}/{1}-{2}'.format(directory,file,da)) # add time from timestamp
    return files

print sorted(get_files("."),key=lambda x: float(x.rsplit(":",1)[-1]),reverse = True)[:5] # sort based on seconds/milisecs
```

Comment: How are you getting the files list with the created times? I think that's the question.

Comment: @mnjeremiah Actually I just need the names of files.

Comment: @NinjaFart, the first example will sort from most recently modified and return the files

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks. Would you mind to explain where/how I would  adjust the timespan - lets say I only want the most recent **files** created within 900 milliseconds.

Comment: ok so you want them within a threshold, I will add to my answer in a few minutes

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks. I updated my question with final code.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of files and their ctimes (or mtimes) then sort it:

```
a = [(os.path.getctime(f), f)for f in os.listdir(os.curdir)]
a.sort()
```

filter the list for files created within one second of the most recent file

```
most_recent = a[-1][0]
b = [thing for thing in a if most_recent - thing[0] <= 1]
```

Comment: You are on to something, but can't get it to work with subdirectories. Your variable naming is a bit confusing too.